# Inserting and deleting spaces in a text array using C

Tags: c, arrays, linked-list

I've managed to create the following output from a program:

```
7.86 ( 8Hm,),  6.82 ( 4Hm,),12.1 ( 1Hs,).
```

I want to either add a space or delete a space depending on what character I am pointing to. Would sscanf allow you to do this?

I was just wondering what would be the easiest way to insert and delete spaces in this text. For example, I want to delete a space between `(` and 'num' eg `8`, but provide a space between `H` and 'letter' eg `m`. So far I have code that looks something like this:

```
typedef struct node {
    int i;
    char array[SIZE];
    struct node* link;
} node;

node* format(void)
{      
    int count = 0;
    int size = list_size(data, sizeof(data)) / 4;

    for (node* ptr = head; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->link)
    {
        int i;
        int j; 

        for (i = 0, j = 0; i < sizeof(ptr->array); i++, j++)
        {             

            if (ptr->array[0] == ' ' && count == 0)
            {                
                count++;
                j--;               
            } 


            else if (ptr->array[i] == ' ' && ptr->array[i-1] == '.')
            {                
                j--;
                ptr->array[i] = ','; 
            }    


            else if (ptr->array[i] == ',' && ptr->array[i-1] == ')')
            {
                if (count == size)
                {                                   
                    ptr->array[i] = '.';
                }
            }        


            ptr->array[j] = ptr->array[i];

        }  

        count++;  


    } 

    return head; 
}
```

Note that the above is currently a linked list of size 3, whereby I created the latter to enable swapping of "groups" of characters and then reverse the order in a specific way. Would it be easier to format if I passed everything back to a single array first?

Any tips/advice would be gratefully received!

Comment: Your question is almost impossible to answer without seeing how you have defined the struct that makes up the linked list, but presuming `node->array[]` is simply a character array containing the string you are formatting, then showing the content (or example content) of the string as it is contained in the list would certainly help people help you. You shouldn't expect folks to have to *reverse-engineer* your string in order to help with the formatting.

Comment: Exactly. Format it correctly in the first place.

Comment: Yes, the node is as follows:

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use `sscanf` to parse correctly the string and then just print it to another string. Manually parsing the string in the way you are doing it will give you no observable speed/memory gain and will just add a ton of code.

#### Example

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    char str[]= "7.86 ( 8Hm,),  6.82 ( 4Hm,),12.1 ( 1Hs,).";

    float f1, f2, f3;
    int i1, i2, i3;

    sscanf(str, "%f ( %dHm,),  %f ( %dHm,),%f ( %dHs,).", &f1, &i1, &f2, &i2, &f3, &i3);
    printf("%f ( %dHm,),  %f ( %dHm,),%f ( %dHs,).\n", f1, i1, f2, i2, f3, i3);

    return 0;
}
```

`scanf` functions are powerful and as you can see you can use them to parse your formated string. When you run the code in this example, it prints this:

```
7.860000 ( 8Hm,),  6.820000 ( 4Hm,),12.100000 ( 1Hs,).
```

The way it works is that `scanf` can ignore characters. So it reads the first float and then ignores blank spaces, ignores a parenthesis, reads an int, ignores Hm and so on.

My `printf` is formating the string the same way it came from the input. You can tweak it to meet your requirements. You should also search around and limit decimal digits. But the basic idea is that you get the data you need from the string and then you can print that data the way you want.

Comment: Hi, sorry yes the node is     typedef struct node {int i; char array[SIZE]; struct node* link;} node;

Comment: Also I want to either add a space or delete a space depending on what character I am pointing to. Would sscanf allow you to do this?

Comment: @Matthew2015 please add the information in these comments: to the **question**.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin performance requirements are relevant to all code bases, but he has not mentioned his. I will edit further my answer giving example with `sscanf`.

Comment: @Weather, I've included the details of the node as a comment above. Is that ok or would you like more details?

Comment: @Matthew2015 I have added your commented definition to the question, since you failed to grasp my advice.

Comment: An honest mistake Weather, we're not here to chastise one another

Comment: Especially with complex format, always a good idea to check the `sscanf()` result before using the values read.

Comment: Can you still rely on sscanf tho if the string length and contents change?

Comment: To allow successful scanning with variant spacing in the source line, suggest `"%f (%d Hm , ) ,%f (%d Hm , ) ,%f (%d Hs , ) ."`.  Pre-pend a space before each text token.  No need for a space before `%d` or `%f`.

Answer (score 0):

Doing the best to understand what you currently have in `ptr-array` and then how to accomplish the reformat, which you appear to want to do `in-place` simply updating `ptr->array` to hold to updated formatted string, then you can build a correctly formatted buffer to replace the current `ptr->array`.

**Note:** the better solution would be separate the values in `ptr->array` into actual separate values and hold that as part of your linked list where you either statically declare an array of structs to hold your `values` and `units` (which is my best guess for `7.86 (8Hm,)`. That would allow you to format the values in any way needed rather than being stuck with what is in `array`. For example:

```
#define USIZE 8

typedef struct values {
    double value;
    char[USIZE];
} values;

typedef struct node {
    int i;
    char array[SIZE];
    values *vals;
    struct node* link;
} node;
```

or, e.g.:

```
typedef struct node {
    int i;
    char array[SIZE];
    values vals[3];
    struct node* link;
} node;
```

Regardless, your original question was how to reformat your existing `ptr->array` removing spaces following `'('` and separating `'8Hm'` to `'8H m'` in your sample data of:

```
7.86 ( 8Hm,),  6.82 ( 4Hm,),12.1 ( 1Hs,).
```

Given that you are iterating over each node in your list, this reformat would presumably only be run once after you have collected/stored all your nodes. One approach is to construct a new buffer holding `array` in its new format and then replace your new `array` with the properly formatted `buffer`.

Yes, there are many ways to do this, but if your reformat criteria is limited, simply walking down `array` with a pointer using the tried and true *inch-worm* method filling your new buffer with the characters in the desired format is about as easy and flexible as anything else.

Below, the example creates a new buffer (`buf[SIZE]`) copies/replaces/removes characters from `ptr->array` and then replaces `ptr->array` with the contents of `buf`.

**NOTE:** I have not run this on any data, so you may need to tweak the logic a bit. This is merely meant to show you an approach that can be used and to make that as close a possible to a solution to your question (to the best I understood it).

**NOTE2:** you can replace the *upper/lower* case conditionals below with `isupper` or `islower` from `ctype.h` if you are not limited to specific headers. Additionally, `memcpy` below will require `string.h`, but can be re-written to simply do the copy without it if that is an issue.

```
node* format(void)
{      
    /* for each node in list */
    for (node* ptr = head; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->link)
    {
        /* declare a pointer to `ptr->array` and `buf` */
        char *p = ptr->array;
        char *pend = p + SIZE;
        char buf[SIZE] = {0};
        char *bp = buf;

        /* for each char in ptr->array */
        while (p < pend)
        {
            /* if not the first char */
            if (p > ptr->array)
            {
                /* if current char is ' ' */
                if (*p == ' ')
                {
                    /* if previous char is one of the following */
                    if (*(p - 1) == '.') *bp++ = ',';
                    if (*(p - 1) == ')') *bp++ = '.';
                    if (*(p - 1) == '(') { p++; continue; } /* remove ' ' after '(' */
                }

                /* if current is lower case & prior is upper, separate */
                else if (('a' <= *(p - 1) && *(p - 1) <= 'z') && ('A' <= *p && *p <= 'Z'))
                {
                    *bp++ = ' ';
                    *bp++ = *p;
                }
                /* default - copy current to buf */
                else
                    *bp++ = *p;
            }
            p++;    /* advance to next char */
        }
        /* copy formatted string to ptr->array */
        memcpy (ptr->array, buf, SIZE);
    } 

    return head; 
}
```

**Note3:** if `SIZE` is a global `#define`, then replace `sizeof (ptr->array)` wtih `SIZE`.

Comment: `p < p + sizeof (ptr->array)` will always be true (both `p` and `sizeof` are non-negative) and thus the `while` will run infinitely.

Comment: Thank you! Good catch. Nothing like testing against `p < p + 2; p++;` `:)`

Comment: Since it is a string, I like testing against `NULL`.

Comment: But there is no guarantee it is null-terminated based on the questioner's code. That was the whole reason what a simple `while (*p)...` wasn't used.